# write value from lable in aspx page

Tags: sql, asp.net, dynamic, menu

I am working to create Dynamic Menu in aspx page reading the ready script from sql , till now i finished from sql part and view the script in lable in aspx page.

how can write this script within the html script using some functions like document.write so will get menu appear in the page

Comment: At least show some code.